# Fastest way to update one big dictionary with another dictionary values if one of the values matches in both dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm working with Python 3.5

I have a dictionary that contains a list of thousands of other smaller dictionaries that looks something like this:

```
bookSnapshot = {
 'ask':[{'Price': 0.013, 'Size': 0.005},{'Price': 0.014, 'Size': 0.009},{...}...], 
 'bid':[{'Price': 0.012, 'Size': 0.005},{'Price': 0.011, 'Size': 0.006},{...}...]
}
```

This is the response that I get from the server when I create a Websocket connection.

After that the server will send me updates on any changes in the dictionary. That look exactly the same as the above dictionary only way smaller.

```
bookUpdate = {
 'ask':[{'Price': 0.013, 'Size': 0.005}], 
 'bid':[{'Price': 0.012, 'Size': 0.000}]
}
```

I want to update the bookSnapshot of any of the 'ask' or 'bid' dictionary 'Price' values matches the bookUpdate dictionary 'bid' or  'ask' 'Price' values. And if the 'Size' is 0 to delete the dictionary from th 'ask' or 'bid' values.

Iterating over both the dictionaries would take way too long. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be inefficient with a list of dictionaries. You can use a 3rd party library such as Pandas instead to perform vectorised operations:

```
bookSnapshot = {
 'ask':[{'Price': 0.013, 'Size': 0.005},{'Price': 0.014, 'Size': 0.009}], 
 'bid':[{'Price': 0.012, 'Size': 0.005},{'Price': 0.011, 'Size': 0.006}]
}

bookUpdate = {
 'ask':[{'Price': 0.013, 'Size': 0.006}], 
 'bid':[{'Price': 0.012, 'Size': 0.000}]
}

import pandas as pd

df_Snapshot = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in bookSnapshot.items()}
df_Update = {k: pd.DataFrame(v).set_index('Price')['Size'] for k, v in bookUpdate.items()}

for k, v in df_Snapshot.items():
    v['Size'] = v['Price'].map(df_Update[k]).fillna(v['Size'])
    v = v[v['Size'] != 0]
    df_Snapshot[k] = v

print(df_Snapshot)

{'ask':    Price   Size
0  0.013  0.006
1  0.014  0.009,
 'bid':    Price   Size
1  0.011  0.006}
```

Then use a dictionary comprehension to convert back to your desired result:

```
res = {k: v.to_dict('records') for k, v in df_Snapshot.items()}

{'ask': [{'Price': 0.013, 'Size': 0.006}, {'Price': 0.014, 'Size': 0.009}],
 'bid': [{'Price': 0.011, 'Size': 0.006}]}
```

Comment: thank you, this not only helps with this problem, but pointed out the next thing I need to learn in Python. Great advice. :)